# The best approach to save kinvey object in Android

Tags: android, kinvey, mbaas

I would like to create an apps with backend service in kinvey. Previously i use Parse.com as my backend service, due to Parse.com is going to stop their service, so i need to consider another mbaas.

i read many reference in internet like http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/datastore or github, but i still got no idea how to make a simple saving data to kinvey in android apps.

Parse.com adding data was easy, just create an new Parse Object like

```
ParseObject object = new ParseObject("booking_details");
object.put("username", struser);
```

Can anyone with experience in Kinvey android apps development give me a short tutorial about saving data? thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that different with Kinvey. But, you must define a java class to model your data first. Kinvey records also always include three meta-data fields: a primary key (_id) and _kmd/_acl to store timestamps and ACLs. So something like this:

```
public class BookingDetails extends GenericJson {
    @Key("_id")
    private String _id; 
    @Key("_kmd")
    private KinveyMetaData meta;
    @Key("_acl")
    private KinveyMetaData.AccessControlList acl;
    public EventEntity(){}  //GenericJson classes must have a public empty constructor
}
```

In this example, I did not actually add the "username" field to the class. But you can, just like the "String _id" field. And add getter/setters for it in your class. But if you like to work it the easy way, and follow the Parse example, you can add dynamic fields, like this:

```
BookingDetails object = new BookingDetails();
object.put("username", struser);
```

Then, first link a Kinvey collection to a local "AppData" object:

```
AsyncAppData<BookingDetails > bookingdetails = mKinveyClient.appData("bookingDetail", BookingDetails.class);
```

and save your "object" to Kinvey:

```
bookingdetails.save(object, new KinveyClientCallback<EventEntity>() {
@Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "failed to save event data", e); 
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(EventEntity r) {
        Log.d("TAG", "saved data for entity "+ r.getName()); 
    }
});
```

(for a full syntax, [see the devcenter](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/datastore#Saving))

Comment: i have a question, because my components like EditText are in MainActivity, how do i pass all the value in EditText to "BookDetails" class?Thank for your reply! I have some clue now.